# .NET Core and C# : IHostedServices don’t run automatically without webHost.Run

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have written the following code in C# running on .NET Core 3.1.

I am trying to think of a cleaner way of doing this.

`IHostedServices` doesn't run automatically without `webHost.Run`

Could somebody suggest?

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)            
    {            
        var webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();  
                  
        if (args.Any(arg => string.Equals(arg, "sqlrate=latest", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))            
        {            
            var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();            
            var sqlWatchers = webHost.Services            
                .GetServices<IHostedService>()            
                .OfType<ISqlCollectionWatcher>()            
                .ToList();

            foreach (var sqlDbWatcher in sqlWatchers)            
            {            
                await sqlDbWatcher.StartAsync(cancellationToken);            
            }
            
            var migrationRunner = webHost.Services.GetService<IMigrationRunner>();            
            var migrationLocator = (MigrationLocator)webHost.Services.GetService<IMigrationLocator>();            
            migrationLocator.Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();            
            var migrationResult = migrationRunner.UpdateToLatest();            
            Console.Write($"Migration result: {migrationResult}"); 
            foreach (var sqlDbWatcher in sqlWatchers)            
            {
                await sqlDbWatcher.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            webHost.Run();
            await webHost.RunAsync();
        }
    }
    
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                var isDevelopment = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
                loggerConfiguration
                    .MinimumLevel.Is(isDevelopment ? LogEventLevel.Debug : LogEventLevel.Information)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", isDevelopment ? LogEventLevel.Debug : LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("System", isDevelopment ? LogEventLevel.Debug : LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .WriteTo.Console(new StackdriverJsonFormatter())
                    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .Enrich.WithOpenTracingContext();
            });
}
```

Comment: The `Run()` is needed, cause it provides the `CancellationToken` that will be *stopped* when the application is going to be closed. And this token is given to all services, etc. So calling `Run()` is needed to run the services.

Comment: A "cleaner way" to do what exactly? A code dump with no explanation doesn't really tell us what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

The example [in Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0) shows you need the run:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

I guess this is "an answer from a reputable source" ;)

> I am trying to think of a cleaner way of doing this.

Don't call run/runasync twice

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's true. You need a run HostedService and you can run only one HostedService as this is how they build in extensions library.

As far as I understand, you want to start additional services if a specific parameter is provided. Best way to do it encapsulate the business to another service, and start that service within your main HostedService. Many people need something similar, and we either make it separate services, or host them within main service.

If you host it in your main service, you also have an advantage of having a CancellationToken so your watchers can gracefully terminate too.

You can check if argument exists, then register your service; if not, then not.

```cs
...
services.AddSingleton<DbWatcherManager>();
...


class MainService {
  MainService (DbWatcherManager watchManager){}
  
  async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken){
    
    await watchManager.StartWatchers(stoppingToken);
    ...

    // run some happy code here and
    // beware of dragons

    ...

  }

}
```